# How to fix HandleSignInResult return false?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I'm making a notes app using firebase auth and realtime database.
I'm stuck at the setup of google authentication.
this is my Code:

```
`package zohar.com.blablabla;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener {
SignInButton signInButton;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
public static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();


    signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.signInButtonGoogle);
    signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    signIn();
}

private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        //connected successfully
        Toast.makeText(this, "You are successfully connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent toMainActivityIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(toMainActivityIntent);
    }
}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    Toast.makeText(this, "We are currently facing with google/'s api issues, 
    please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}`
```

The problam is that every time when I click on the sign in button its not even showing the account picker (I dont know if its importent but I have more than 1 google accounts on my emulator). When I click it the screen turns little dark and than turns regular.
Everytime HandleSignInResult returns False.

*I did register my project and insert the sha-1.
**Sorry if I made some spelling/grammar mistakes. I'm still learning english and it's not my primary language.
Thanks.

EDIT: This are the warns:

```
    08-14 10:52:34.116 2355-2355/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using 
    defaults: x86
    08-14 10:52:34.404 2355-2355/zohar.com.notescloud W/System: ClassLoader 
    referenced unknown path: /data/app/zohar.com.notescloud-2/lib/x86
    08-14 10:52:34.564 2355-2378/zohar.com.notescloud W/DynamiteModule: Local 
    module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
    08-14 10:52:34.579 2355-2378/zohar.com.notescloud W/DynamiteModule: Local 
    module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
    08-14 10:52:35.009 2355-2355/zohar.com.notescloud W/art: Before Android 4.1, 
    method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter 
 android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
08-14 10:52:35.209 2355-2355/zohar.com.notescloud W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
08-14 10:52:35.405 2355-2355/zohar.com.notescloud W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000006/n/x86
08-14 10:52:35.856 2355-2430/zohar.com.notescloud W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
08-14 10:52:36.030 2355-2355/zohar.com.notescloud W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
c
```

Debug:

```
08-14 11:02:08.029 2355-11693/zohar.com.notescloud D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=46612, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=LoginActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3256989730768445770}]
08-14 11:02:08.072 2355-11693/zohar.com.notescloud D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=LoginActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=3256989730768445770, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SignInHubActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3256989730768445773}]
08-14 11:02:08.178 2355-11693/zohar.com.notescloud D/FA: Connected to remote service
08-14 11:02:08.183 2355-2430/zohar.com.notescloud D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9aa2b320: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9c741ef0)
08-14 11:02:08.205 2355-2430/zohar.com.notescloud D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9aa2b320: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9c741ef0)
08-14 11:02:08.947 2355-2355/zohar.com.notescloud D/SignInActivity: handleSignInResult:false
08-14 11:02:08.953 2355-11693/zohar.com.notescloud D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=SignInHubActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=3256989730768445773, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=LoginActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3256989730768445770}]
```

EDIT2: FIXED!
I was so dumb and gave the auto-completion make GOOGLE_SIGN_IN to GOOGLE_GAMES_SIGN_IN.
Sry guys.

Comment: An error message should have been passed to the `GoogleSignInResult`. Can you post that here?

Comment: check this ans https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34324258/google-sign-in-not-working-android?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @Milk this are the warns, seems to be no errors...    (I'll edit in question)

Comment: @VinayakB I tried - not working... but thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: FIXED! Thx. I feel so dumb now :/