# Android - GoogleSignInResult always failing

Tags: android, google-signin

I have followed the tutorial here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating
to integrate Google sign in into my app.

However, the `GoogleSignInResult.isSuccess()` is always false. `GoogleSignInStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(googleSignInResult.getStatus().getStatusCode())` shows `INTERNAL_ERROR`. The docs [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes.html#INTERNAL_ERROR) say "retrying should solve the problem", but it doesn't.

Any ideas on what's wrong?

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34117263/android-google-signin-not-working-in-debug-mode-googlesigninresult-is-false), but I have added the `json` file.

Comment: Did you configure your project in Google Developer Console and provided correct signature?

Comment: You can have a look at [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56340297/2289835)

Comment: You can refer to [this answer](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/360#issuecomment-404681049)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem was that I was running the app from Android Studio (without setting up `signingConfig`), so the app wasn't signed with my certificate, which Google Sign-in requires.

Comment: I should have paid more attention to this zero-vote answer!

Comment: Plus, you *can* run it from Android Studio with the `Build Types` which has `Signing Config` set with the right certificate.

Comment: True. I hadn't set it up before but I have now and it's all good. The API should really provide a more specific error message, though.

Comment: @VedavyasBhat How do you setup signingConfig in Android Studio?

Comment: @emaillenin It's an Android thing, not an Android Studio thing. Here's the tutorial: http://developer.android.com/intl/in/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: One line answer : create signed apk thats it.

Answer (score 1):

If you run from Android studio without signingConfigs, then it is using your debug key store to sign. You can try register your package name + debug key SHA1 in dev console for easy development:

[Test google signin on Android in development phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34811645/test-google-signin-on-android-in-development-phase/35075641#35075641)