# Test google signin on Android in development phase

Tags: android, android-studio, google-signin

Google signin is always returning signed-out. It always fails when pushing the app on the device using Android studio.

However, when I install the signed app it works.

How can I make google sign in works while we are still developing the app?

Answer (score 13):

At development time, you are probably using your debug key store:

Get the SHA-1 of your debug key cert:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

And register it together your package name in developer console [Credentials page](https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/apiui/credential) as well. (Each pair requires one registration)

You can refer to this post's answer for details:
[Occured an INTERNAL_ERROR when requestEmail from GoogleSignInOptions Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942692/occured-an-internal-error-when-requestemail-from-googlesigninoptions-android)

Or see below blogpost to understand more about OAuth clients registration:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/03/registering-oauth-clients-for-google.html

Comment: Thank god! You saved my day! My mistake was to only sign the production key. You also have to add your debug.keystore sha-1. Seems to be a common mistake by developers